# How to compile Clisp 2.46?

Tags: installation, lisp, common-lisp, configure

When I try to compile the newest version of Clisp on Ubuntu 8.04 I always get this error after running configure:

```
Configure findings:
FFI:        no (user requested: default)
readline:   yes (user requested: yes)
libsigsegv: no, consider installing GNU libsigsegv
./configure: libsigsegv was not detected, thus some features, such as
generational garbage collection and
stack overflow detection in interpreted Lisp code
cannot be provided.
Please do this:
  mkdir tools; cd tools; prefix=`pwd`/i686-pc-linux-gnu
  wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libsigsegv/libsigsegv-2.5.tar.gz
  tar xfz libsigsegv-2.5.tar.gz
  cd libsigsegv-2.5
  ./configure --prefix=${prefix} && make && make check && make install
  cd ../..
  ./configure --with-libsigsegv-prefix=${prefix} --with-readline --with-unicode --with-module=i18n --with-module=gdbm --with-module=pcre --with-module=readline --with-module=regexp
If you insist on building without libsigsegv, please pass
  --ignore-absence-of-libsigsegv
to this script:
  ./configure --ignore-absence-of-libsigsegv --with-readline --with-unicode --with-module=i18n --with-module=gdbm --with-module=pcre --with-module=readline --with-module=regexp
```

I've tried doing as requested, but it didn't help: it seems to ignore the `--with-libsigsegv-prefix` option. I also tried putting installing libsigsegv in a standard location (`/usr/local`). Oh, and of course, Ubuntu tells me that libsigsegv and libsigsegv-dev are installed in the system.

I'd really like to be able to compile this version of Clips, as it introduces some serious improvements over the version shipped with Ubuntu (I'd also like to have PCRE).

Comment: This still seems to be a problem today on Lucid & CLISP 2.49.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my notes from compiling CLISP on Ubuntu in the past, hope this helps:

```
sudo apt-get install libsigsegv-dev libreadline5-dev

# as of 7.10, Ubuntu's libffcall1-dev is broken and I had to get it from CVS
# and make sure CLISP didn't use Ubuntu's version.
sudo apt-get remove libffcall1-dev libffcall1
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.sv.gnu.org:/sources/libffcall co -P ffcall
cd ffcall; ./configure; make
sudo make install

cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@clisp.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/clisp co -P clisp
cd clisp
./configure --with-libffcall-prefix=/usr/local --prefix=/home/luis/Software
ulimit -s 16384
cd src; make install
```

Comment: Apparently, the "release" tarball is badly broken, and getting the source from CVS worked like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at 'config.log' it might tell you why configure is not finding libsigsegv

Comment: it says: "configure:31142: checking for libsigsegv configure:31200: result: no, consider installing GNU libsigsegv". Not really helpful :P